# Composer out of memory

Tags: sylius

After installing sylius (standart)

```
composer create-project -s alpha sylius/sylius-standard acme // its OK
composer update // ERROR

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 58720256 bytes) in phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 73
```

Ref Ask in GitHub ([#6854](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/6854))

I have increased memory_limit (php) to 1G, 3G, -1 and same results.

```
My sistem:
Windows x64
Processor Phenom x955 x4
RAM 4GB
Composer 1.2.2
PHP 7 (I tried with 5.6 too)
```

The ask: Which server would need minimally to implement sylius?

Or will this problem only happen with composer?

Comment: Instead run composer install. update uses alot more memory. Once you've run composer install once you can generally run the update after that

Comment: Did that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue under Windows 10 x64.
I noticed that my php installation was PHP7 32 bit version (so max allowed memory usage was 4GB) and I had xdebug enabled.

Afert installing PHP7 64-bit with xdebug disabled and setting memory_limit to -1 everything works fine. 
Probably composer is using more than 4GB memory under Windows when dowloading all required bundles for Sylius during installation or it was PHP 32bit + composer issue...

Comment: you are right, here is a tutorial how to use a 64bit PHP on windows for composer updating: http://sebastianviereck.de/en/Windows-composer-update-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-1610612736-bytes-exhausted/